# Add summary plot at the end of facet_wrap ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'd like to add a summary plot at the end of my facet_wrap plot, of what the plot would look like if I hadn't employed the facet_wrap. For example:

```
test=data.frame(x=runif(1000,min=-1,max=1),y=as.character(sample(x=1:8, size=1000, replace=TRUE)))

ggplot(test, aes(x=x, fill=x)) +
  geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE)+
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_wrap(~y)
```

This produces this plot:

[image: histogram of random data with a facet_wrap]

However, since I  have that extra corner in the lower right, I'd like to add a summary plot of all the data, as if I hadn't employed variable y. It would look like this:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, fill=x)) +
      geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE)+
      theme_minimal()+
      ggtitle('All Data')
```

[image: All Random data in Histogram]

Is there a way to do this, perhaps with grid.arrange?

Cheers!

Edited to adjust the test data to better represent the real data:

Note, with fake data the following code works, but not with my real data.

```
bins <- 200
cols <- c("#0072B2",'#253f4b',"#0072B2","#D55E00","#F0E442","#D55E00")
colGradient <- colorRampPalette(cols)
cut.cols <- colGradient(bins)
cuts <- cut

ggplot(test, aes(x=x, fill=cut(x,bins))) +
  geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE, binwidth = 0.06)+
  geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE,
    data = ~ transform(.x, y = "All Data")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cut.cols,labels=levels(cuts)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cut.cols,labels=levels(cuts)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-1,0,1), labels=c('dusk', 'dawn','dusk'), limits = c(-1.1,1.1))+
  
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_wrap(~y)
```

normalizedtime==x, station==y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired would be to use a second `geom_histogram` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

ggplot(test, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_histogram(
    data = ~ transform(.x, y = "All Data")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~y)
```

[image]

**UPDATE** Here is the adapted code based on the data you provided via `dput`. Still puzzled what's the reason for the error you got when you applied the code to your data. Note: I adapted the code to put the `"All Data"` category last. Additionally, I used a different approach to color the bars using `after_stat()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

DPHdol$station <- factor(
  DPHdol$station,
  levels = c(unique(DPHdol$station), "All Data")
)

bins <- 100
cols <- c("#0072B2", "#253f4b", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#F0E442", "#D55E00")
colGradient <- colorRampPalette(cols)
cut.cols <- colGradient(bins)
cuts <- cut

ggplot(DPHdol, aes(x = normalizedtime)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(fill = after_stat(factor(x))),
    bins = bins
  ) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(fill = after_stat(factor(x))),
    data = ~ transform(.x, station = factor("All Data", levels = levels(station))), 
    bins = bins
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cut.cols, labels = levels(cuts)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cut.cols, labels = levels(cuts)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), 
    labels = c("dusk", "dawn", "dusk"),
    limits = c(-1.1, 1.1)
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~station) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, but for some reason on my real data this just produces the error  -- Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'x' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred. -- 

I am not sure what to look for in rlang::last_trace().

Comment: Well, I have used `.x` not `x` which is an important difference when using `~` to specify an inline function.

Comment: I have also used .x. :(  Oddly, when I run this trick on the fake data, it works exactly as you show. It is on my real data, and I don't know how to better accurately create reproducible data for this question.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Just had a second look and the error is raised by `aes()`, i.e. according to the error message there is no column named `x` in the data used for the second `geom_histogram`. Weird.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a snippet of your real data via `dput()` and your real code which gives the error?

Comment: The data seems very large and unruly to add a snippet, but I've adjusted the sample data to better represent the real data.

Comment: See my update, where I now use your extensive dput(). :D

Comment: YES THAT GETS ME CLOSE!  I have to adjust some aesthetics, but otherwise you found it! Thank you!